# Show tweets from all the users that I've chosen to follow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, nomethoderror, find-all-references

Actually, I just want to create a profile page for a user(similar to what you have in actual Twitter), and I want this page to display the tweets from all the users I've chosen to follow.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
def profile
    if current_user
        @tweet = Tweet.new
        all_ids = current_user.followeds.map(&:id).push(current_user.id)
        @tweets = Tweet.find_all_by_user_id(all_ids)
    else
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

'Profile action' is in UsersController.

---

My routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
resources :users, only: [:show]
resources :tweets
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
root to: "home#index"   
get '/profile', to: 'users#profile', as: 'profile'
```

---

Now, when I visit localhost:3000/profile, it says:-

**NoMethodError in UsersController#profile**

**undefined method `find_all_by_user_id' for #**

What should I do to resolve this issue?
Let me know if you need some more code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is Tweet a model? rails version?

Comment: Yes, Tweet is a model. Rails: 4.1.6. Ruby: 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_all_by` style dynamic methods are deprecated in [Rails 4](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

Use `where`,

```
@tweets = Tweet.where(user_id: all_ids)
```